# IIS 7 and 503 error for file copy access denied problem

Tags: iis, windows-7, iis-7

I'm running Windows 7 SP 1 and have just turned on IIS 7. Just trying to access the default page it creates I get a 503 error, and the application pool stops. I look in the event log and I find the error:

> Windows cannot copy file \?\C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\SQM\iesqmdata_setup0.sqm to location \?\C:\Users\TEMP.IIS APPPOOL.000\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\SQM\iesqmdata_setup0.sqm. This error may be caused by network problems or insufficient security rights.
>
> DETAIL - Access is denied.

I tried making the TEMP.IIS APPPOOOL.000 folder available to everyone. I tried making Users available to everyone. No luck, it still dies with the same error.

What is happening here, and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 14):

It sounds like you're having the same problem as details in this [IIS.NET forums thread](http://forums.iis.net/p/1180636/1992024.aspx). You didn't mention if you have x64 Windows 7 or not. Suspect that your development machine is misconfigured somehow; sounds like the uninstallation and reinstallation of IIS7 would help/fix.

Suggested courses of action:

- Open IIS and its Application Pools. Open "DefaultAppPool" and any other Application Pools in use.
- Click Advanced Settings for each of these. Ensure the "Load User Profile" is set to 'False'
- Also ensure that the "Set Application Pool Defaults" has the Load User Profile set to False."

Comment: I've got the same problem, now, several years after this question was asked, and it's about an sqm file that cannot be copied. Since I don't consider this file important, I simply deleted it. Now my app pool doesn't stop and I didn't do modifications to any setting.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem in my development environment (Windows 8.1). Instead of disabling the load user profile as suggested by P.Campbell, I went ahead and changed the permission of the sqm file to allow modify accesses for IUSR, IIS_IUSRS and Network Service. In my case, the sqm file was not able to show me the file owner in which I taken over with my user account.

Basically, my problem was solved by giving the correct permission for both source and destination files/folders.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here - http://forums.iis.net/p/1180636/1992024.aspx

- Open IIS Manager
- Find the App Pool that is causing the problem
- Open Advanced Properties
- Change 'Load User Profile' to **false**

Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with all these Application Pool issues in IIs, I found the problem and the solution. This may help you.

Each application pool on each website in Microsoft's Internet Information Server creates its own user account and folder under the "c:\Users" directory when the pool is created and first run. Its actually a virtual user account and should be named for the Application Pool assigned to your web application in IIs. In most development environments, its the default website or "DefaultAppPool". It uses this temporary user account to run the pool. Each website should have a named user pool account. This User folder is used by the pool and ASP.NET for caching and writing of file resources and other things used by IIs, ASP.NET, and this virtual account.

In some setups people are not seeing this folder but a "TEMP" folder (like you have) when the IIs web site is accessed and using the pool.

If you instead see a "TEMP" folder in the Users folder you have a broken application pool account in IIs and in the Registry. The pool is creating the TEMP folder as a backup for this virtual account, which might not have the right security setup. I had this exact scenario.

To fix it go to the registry under:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList
See if you have a SID user account with the ".bak" extension for a DefaultAppPool user account. If so delete it and restart your PC. Test your website again, making sure its actually setup to use DefaulAppPool. It should now recreate the "DefaultAppPool" folder in Users, recreate the registry entry for DefaulAppPool user, and your error should go away.

You can delete the TEMP user folder at that point under the Users folder. (Keep in mind if your web app has been storing cached information critical to users of the website, some of that might have to be inserted into the new DefaultAppPool user folder. But for most of us, just delete it.)

I also found I had to add this kooky virtual application pool account to my local database so the worker process and app pool accnt could have the rights to grab data from SQL Server: Just go into SQL Server and under logins add "IIs AppPool\DefaultAppPool" and then assign it as a user to your databases.

(btw whomever dreamed up this virtual application pool account system is nuts....its way too complicated and convoluted to sort out)

After I did this, all my stack overflow errors went away in Visual Studio for my web application, all data connections fired perfectly, all write permission to the default User profile stored properly, and all the restarting and crashing of the Application Pool in IIs ended completely. :)